# Admin privledges for functions, how it works?

Tags: assembly, admin, uac

I am interested how PC recognize that X function requires admin privledges.

Let me think, lets check two things:
the first one is C# code, second one is ASM code.

If C# requires admin privledges, then ASM also need them?

Sometimes its hard to write simple program for limited accounts

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to be one. :-) It got more complete than I thought it was when I started it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system decides.

Since the ASM and C# code are doing the same thing, they both have to use the same operating system. It's the same as if you had the only key to a door and people have to ask you to use it to get in. It doesn't matter if they ask by email or by telephone call, they still have to ask you for the key and you have to decide if they get it or not.

If you're having trouble writing simple programs for limited accounts, it's because you're trying to do things that aren't allowed for limited accounts. :-)